# Forms not passing data to database but no error Laravel 5.8.22

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying out a multiple-data insert into multiple tables according to this [tutorial](http://www.tsdurjoy.com/2019/01/laravel-multiple-data-insert-into_20.html). I replicated the project but the data doesn't get through to the database when I insert with the forms. I can see the data when I manually insert through PhPMyAdmin, so I doubt it's a database connection problem.

The the **Form View**:

```html
<form>
    <section>
        <div class="panel panel-header">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="customer_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name">
                    </div></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="customer_address" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Address">
                    </div></div>
            </div></div>
        <div class="panel panel-footer" >
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Budget</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th><a href="#" class="addRow"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product_name[]" class="form-control" required=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="brand[]" class="form-control"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity" required=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="budget[]" class="form-control budget"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="form-control amount"></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success"></td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.addRow').on('click',function(){
        addRow();
    });
    function addRow()
    {
        var tr='<tr>'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="product_name[]" class="form-control" required=""></td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="brand[]" class="form-control"></td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity" required=""></td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="budget[]" class="form-control budget"></td>'+
            ' <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="form-control amount"></td>'+
            '<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>'+
            '</tr>';
        $('tbody').append(tr);
    };
    $('.remove').live('click',function(){
        var last=$('tbody tr').length;
        if(last==1){
            alert("you can not remove last row");
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        }

    });
</script>
```

The **OrderController store** function:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data=$request->all();
    $lastid=Orders::create($data)->id;
    if(count($request->product_name) > 0) {
        foreach($request->product_name as $item=>$v) {
            $data2=array(
                         'orders_id'=>$lastid, 
                         'product_name'=>$request->product_name[$item],
                         'brand'=>$request->brand[$item], 
                         'quantity'=>$request->quantity[$item], 
                         'budget'=>$request->budget[$item], 
                         'amount'=>$request->amount[$item]            
                         );
            Items::insert($data2);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','data insert successfully');
}
```

And the **routes** are:

```php
Route::post('/orders','OrderController@store');
Route::get('/orders','OrderController@index');
Route::get('/items/{id}','OrderController@items');
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is it just a compatibility issue?
Thanks

Comment: please, do a `dd($request->all());` at the top of the store function and post the result.  It would also be useful to see what the form looks like in the view, especially the inputs that are not saved.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ There's still no change with that addition. You mean how the form looks in the browser? or the code for the view?

Comment: Excuse me. I just added it @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the `action` (and `method`) attributes to your `<form>` tag. That's why the form is not sending the data.
Also you will need to send the csrf token in a `POST` request.

```
<form method="POST" action="/orders">
    @csrf
    // ...
</form>
```

Comment: With this update I just get an array at `/orders` `array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "broTGuAStn5sYSyqg6nsv6iHp3Kw1Wy4qf61yJs0"
  "customer_name" => "Batman"
  "customer_address" => "Gotham"
  "product_name" => array:1 [▶]
  "brand" => array:1 [▶]
  "quantity" => array:1 [▶]
  "budget" => array:1 [▶]
  "amount" => array:1 [▶]
].`  It still doesn't get to the database.

Comment: oh, remove the dd($request->all()); in your controller